# HFM Smartview VBA CODE

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code for Smartview. In this Code I want to exclude one sheet (Sheet name "POV") how to modify the code to exclude the above sheet. Please help Me.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function HypMenuVRefresh Lib "HsAddin" () As Long

Sub refreshWS()

    Dim Count, i As Integer

    i = 1

    Count = Worksheets.Count

    Do While i <= Count
        pctCompl = (i - Count)
        Application.StatusBar = "TOTAL WORKSHEETS    " & Count & "   " & pctCompl & "  " & "SHEETS PENDING "
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

          Sheets(i).Select


        Call HypMenuVRefresh


        i = i + 1

   Loop

    MsgBox "ALL SHEETS COMPLETED"

Application.StatusBar = "COMPLETED"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change:

```
Sheets(i).Select
HypMenuVRefresh
```

To:

```
If Worksheets(i).Name<>"POV" Then
    Worksheets(i).Select
     HypMenuVRefresh
End If
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help, But i have tried with the above code, but its not ignoring the Sheet "POV". Can u please help me

Comment: What kind of Sheet is it: a Worksheet or a Chart Sheet?

Comment: The subject sheet is 1st sheet of the workbook. can u please help me to change the code as below. Like we need to select active worksheet and call HypMenuVRefresh, then select next sheet again call HypMenuVRefresh, like this for all sheets. This will be more helpful for me. Please help

Comment: you just have to make that substitution in your very code. Once done, try stepping through the code. 1) Place a breakpoint in `If Worksheets(i).Name<>"POV" Then` statement 2) run the macro 3) when macro stops, type in the Immediate window `?Worksheets(i).Name` and press return to see the name of current worksheet 4) press F8 to see what statement the code will switch to 5) repeat steps 3 and 4 till the end and see what's going on